# Facing error after flutter 1.17 update. Couldn't figure out was it the problem due to update or not

Tags: flutter, dart

Compiler message:

> ```
> /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:32:9:   
> Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor   
> that takes no arguments.   const Intent(this.key) : assert(key !=   
> null);
>            ^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:80:9:   
> Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor   
> that takes no arguments.   const Action(this.intentKey) :   
> assert(intentKey != null);
>            ^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:145:9:  
> Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor   
> that takes no arguments.   const ActionDispatcher();
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null build failed.
> ```

Note:  Facing this problem for a newly created app also.

Comment: can you add code, where you are facing issue ?

Comment: im facing this problem for a newly created app also.

Comment: are you using flutter_datetime_picker packgae ?

Comment: No. Im facing this even with the flutter team startup code

Comment: i reinstalled flutter then it worked...i think the problem was with the framework revision due to improper update of flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled flutter resolved the issue. I think the problem was with the framework revision due to improper update of flutter.

<sub>Note: Answer provided by [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9783545/adil-tuladhar) on comment section.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Use this Command in your terminal to solve this issue